# kubernetes - copy a file from master node to kops server with kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, cp, kops

I have a `.pcap` file on the master node, which I want to view in Wireshark on the local machine. I access the Kubernetes cluster via the Kops server by ssh from the local machine. I checked `kubectl cp --help` but provides a way to cp a file from remote pod to kops server.

If anyone knows how to bring a file from Master Node -> Kops Server -> Local machine, please share your knowledge! Thanks!

Comment: What is "kOps server" to you? There is no component that has that name in the kOps architecture. Do you perhaps refer to a normal "worker node"? As in a node that is not a master node?

Comment: @OleMarkusWith I refer to kops server an EC2 instance from where I access K8s cluster and run kubectl commands from.

Comment: So you have a dedicated remote machine from where you operate kOps? I would think you can use `scp` to copy from master to that machine, and then from your local machine. You could also do an SSH tunnel, I suspect.

Comment: @OleMarkusWith Hey Thanks for this suggestion! I was able to scp directly. Initially I though the only way might be through kubectl command. This was an easy solution. Thanks!

Comment: Post it as solution so others who encounter similar issue can your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is simple - `scp`, thanks to @OleMarkusWith's quick response.

All I did was:

On Kops Server:

`scp admin@<master-node's-external-ip>:/path/to/file /dest/path`

On local machine:

`scp <kops-server-ip>:/path/to/file /dest/path`

Comment: i used ```scp root@<master-node's ip>:/path/to/file /dest/path```